# Date and time extraction from Excel file in Python or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have an Excel file with a column that contain both date and time in a single cells as follows:

2020-07-10T13:32:01+00:00

I'm wondering how to extract this cell, split date and time (that are separated by a "T") and write them into 2 new columns "Date" and "Time", and able to use them afterwards to, for example, do Time math operations.

I'd have a start from pandas:

```
    df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
    def convert_excel_time(excel_time):
    return pd.to_datetime()
```

but I actually don't know if it is achievable with pandas.

If I have this:

[image]

I would like to calculate how many minutes passed (for the same date) for the same ID column (2nd column).

I guess I can use python tdelta, or is there a pandas alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can parse most dates formats using

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(df["name of your date column"])
```

You can also cast the desired column to [`datetime64` which is Numpy dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)

```
df = df.astype({"column name": "datetime64"})
```

Comment: Thanks. df = df.astype({"column name": "datetime64"})  returned me a correct formatting. I updated my question - how to perform a tdelta operation in pandas or python?